# Arguments check controll logic and syntax confusion

Tags: bash

I am trying to validate users input to a small script I am writing that checks that there should be: 2 arguments and the the first argument should be wither 'mount' or ' unmount'

I have the following:

```
if [ ! $# == 2 ] || [ $1 != "mount" -o $1 != "unmount" ]; then
```

However it seems to be a bit overzelouse at meeting the conditions I want. For example with the current || operator, nothing gets past the validator but if I use the && operator everything does.

```
if [ ! $# == 2 ] && [ $1 != "mount" -o $1 != "unmount" ]; then
```

Can someone help me figure this out?

Here is the whole block and intended usage

```
if [ ! $# == 2 ] || [ $1 != "mount" -o $1 != "unmount" ]; then
  echo "Usage:"
  echo "encmount.sh mount remotepoint       # mount the remote file system"
  echo "encmount.sh unmount remotepoint   # unmount the remote file system"
  exit
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
if [ "$#" -ne 2 ] || [ "$1" != "mount" -a "$1" != "unmount" ]; then
    echo "Usage:"
    echo "encmount.sh mount remotepoint       # mount the remote file system"
    echo "encmount.sh unmount remotepoint   # unmount the remote file system"
    exit -1
fi
echo "OK"
```

You have a small logical error in your test, since you should enter the usage branch if `$1` is not equal to both `"mount"` and `"unmount"`. Also you should compare numbers with the `-eq` and `-ne` operators ([see here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html)), or use the `((` `))`.

Note that you should quote your variables inside a `test` (`[` `]`)

You can also combine the two expressions like this:

```
if [ "$#" -ne 2 -o \( "$1" != "mount" -a "$1" != "unmount" \) ]; then
```

If you have bash, you can also use the `[[` `]]` syntax:

```
if [[ $# -ne 2 || ( $1 != "mount" && $1 != "unmount" ) ]]; then
```